# Is there a chemical treatment for pipes to reduce or eliminate leaching of lead into tap water?

Tags: environmental-chemistry, water-treatment

Given events in Flint, Michigan, where a switch to acidic river water in the city water supply resulted in leaching of lead into tap water from the insides of pipes, I wonder -- has anyone has heard of a chemical treatment for pipes that would reduce or eliminate further leaching of lead into the water?

Comment: I found this http://cen.acs.org/articles/93/web/2015/03/Lead-Dioxide-Coating-Pipes-Help.html

Comment: The best way to avoid leaching of lead into water is to treat the *water* not the pipes. Leaching is highly dependent on what is in the water and it is is far easier to fix the water than to treat every pipe. Though, of course, the best solution is to completely replace the lead pipes with plastics or copper.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases the Langlier Saturation Index can be adjusted so a small carbonate scale barely forms on a pipe to prevent leaching.  The opposite may have happened to the index making the water corrosive when the water supply was switched.

This adjustment must be done by qualified professionals because if this index is too high the pipes will clog.